# I think I'm messing around ... Rails params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, before-filter

I search a lot in those questions but I don't really see my problem and I hope I will ...

( I'm used to code in C, C++ etc... but I'm a newbie in rails ... )

I have a sign_up view and when I submit, rails automatically set every fields of the user that are filled in the form. It's cool but now I want to create a new text_field and take what the user enter as text in this text_field and uses it later without setting any other user's field, I have been told to use before_create and params or things like that but then I'm a noob ...
In haml :

```
do |f|
  = f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email"
```

works well (it set the email field with what the user enters)

```
do |f|
  = f.text_field NewVarThatIsNotAFieldOfCurrentNewUser, :placeholder => "referral code"
```

Then ofc, this error happens.

```
Error : undefined local variable or method `NewVarThatIsNotAFieldOfCurrentNewUser' (for the user class ofc)
```

If you want more information/code I'll edit this question :)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby / Rails is *much* simpler than C++

You don't need to "declare" new variables every time you want to use them - you just populate them in order to delcare them. Further, Ruby / Rails is [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), meaning that everything you do needs to be based around Objects.

---

**Var**

Your error is stated as such:

```
undefined local variable or method `NewVarThatIsNotAFieldOfCurrentNewUser'
```

What this means is that you're trying to load a variable which you have not created yet. I mentioned you don't need to declare variables in the same way as C++, but you *do* need to populate them with data, or at least have them accessible to your app

In order to do this, you'll need to declare & populate the variable in your controller, although this brings me onto my next point -- regarding the context in which you're trying to use the variable.

--

**Objects**

As Rails / Ruby is object-orientated, it means that everything you do needs to centre around *objects*. This is why your error states `local variable or method` -- objects have "methods" as well as data

Anyway, the way to fix your issue is to make sure that the *attribute* that your user has is available when you call / create the new `User` object. To do this, I would recommend using [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor), although I'm not entirely sure what you're asking to be honest.

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :new_attribute
end

#app/views/users/sign_up.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :new_attribute %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will create what's known as a `virtual attribute`, which means that it will not be saved into the database (as the database does not have the corresponding attribute supported)

---

**Fix**

If you wanted to collect data for a "new" attribute the user does not have data for (which is still in the database), you'll likely want to use the following:

```
#app/views/users/sign_up.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :attribute %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In regards to what you're asking - I believe the `attr_accessor` method is the most apt. This will give you the ability to "reuse" the data which is submitted without relying on storing it in the database.

--

**MVC**

Finally, to give you some more context - I don't know how familiar you are with [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (I presume relatively), but I figured I give you some ideas on how Rails applications work:

[image]

MVC means that you have a `Model`, `view` and `Controller`. These all work together to provide a base level of functionality for your application - providing you with the capacity to create & edit data from your DB.

I mention this because if you can appreciate how Rails works from an architectural standpoint, you'll be in a much better position to make use of it. For example, you mention you're confused with `before_create`, and then tag the question with `before_action`.

These two callbacks serve different parts of the Rails framework, and will not, therefore, perform the same functionality.

> -- [`before_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) is for your `Model`
>
> -- [`before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action) is for your `Controller`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`FormTagHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) module to create *"form tags that don't rely on an Active Record object"*:

```
= text_field_tag 'your_independent_field'
```

This will be available as `params[:your_independent_field]` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag method.
In rails if you create form like:

```
= form_for @some_obj do |f|
```

Than every field created with notation f.something (like f.text_field, f.submit) will be associated with @some_obj object. So when you send form all fields values will be accessible from params hash with params[:some_obj] (for example params[:something][:email])

You can use something like:

```
= form_for @some_obj do |f|
  = text_field_tag 'some_custom_param'
  = f.text_field :something
```

And after send your params hash will be:

```
params[:some_obj][:something] # => will hold value of :something text field
params[:some_custom_param] # => will hold value of 'some_custom_param' text field ;)
```